# Call to undefined function cal_days_in_month() error while running from server

Tags: php

I am running a php project from xampp ,it is running with out any error.When I am trying to run the same project from server it is throwing an error `Call to undefined function cal_days_in_month()`.Is there any permissions that I have to give from server side?

Comment: [Installation](http://php.net/manual/en/calendar.installation.php).

Answer (score 14):

Try

```
date('t', mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, 1, $year));
```

And I found in internet that it requires PHP to compile with calendar support:

> recompile PHP with the "--enable-calendar" option

Comment: Thanks for response.But how to recompile php.

Answer (score 7):

if you are receiving this error, you can try using this function instead of recompiling with php and trying enable the calendar option as I was unable to enable the calendar.

```
function days_in_month($month, $year){
    // calculate number of days in a month
    return $month == 2 ? ($year % 4 ? 28 : ($year % 100 ? 29 : ($year % 400 ? 28 : 29))) : (($month - 1) % 7 % 2 ? 30 : 31);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Those are issues related to php expansion. To fix that you need to install **php-calendar**

```
sudo apt-get install php-calendar
```

Or you can enable(archlinux) it in php.ini file

```
extension=calendar
```

Comment: Not require external libraries https://www.php.net/manual/en/calendar.requirements.php

Answer (score 0):

I am using docker with docker compose, this worked for me:

```
RUN docker-php-ext-install calendar
```

then:

```
docker compose build app
docker compose up
```